# Best way to import data in Python? XML?

Tags: python

I am very new to python and want to make a script for a spreadsheet I use at work. Basically, i need to associate an address with multiple 5 digit reference codes. There are multiple addresses with a corresponding group of reference codes.

i.e:

```
Address:
1234 E. 32nd Street,
New York, NY, 10001
Ref #'s
RL081
RL089
LA063
Address 2:
etc....
```

I need my script to look up a location by ref code. This information is then used to build a new spreadsheet (each row needs an address and the address is looked up using a ref code). What is the best way to use this info in python? Would it be a dictionary? Should I put the addresses / ref codes into an XML type file?

Thanks

Edit (clarification):
Basically, I have those addresses and corresponding ref codes (they could be in a plain text document, I could organize them in a spreadsheet, or whatever so python can use them). The script I'm building needs to use those ref codes to enter an address into a new spreadsheet. Basically, I input a half complete spreadsheet and the script fills in the addresses based on the ref code in each row.

Comment: How many addresses do you have?

Comment: about 8 with about 150 ref codes among them

Answer (score 3):

*Import into what?*

If you have everything in a spreadsheet, Python has a very good [CSV reader library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html). Once you've read it in, the challenge becomes what to do with it.

If you are looking at a medium term solution, I'd recommend looking at using [SQLite](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) to set up a simple spreadsheet that can manage the information in a more structured way. SQLite scales well in the beginning stages of a project and it becomes a trivial case to insert into a fully-fledged RDBMS like PostGreSQL or MySQL if it becomes neccessary.

From there it becomes a case of writing the libraries you need to manipulate your data, and present it. In the initial stages this can be done using the command line but by using an SQL database this can be exposed through a webpage for multiple people down the line without worrying about managing data integrity.

Comment: Basically, I have those addresses and corresponding ref codes (they could be in a plain text document, I could organize them in a spreadsheet, or whatever). The script I'm building need to use those ref code to enter an address into a new spreadsheet. Basically, I input a half complete spreadsheet and the script fills in the addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use JSON over XML for storing data that will later be used in python. The [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module is fairly robust and easy to use. Since you will be performing lookups I would definitely loading the information as a python dictionary. Since you'll be querying by ref codes you'll want to use those for keys and have the address as the value.

Answer (score -1):

> I need my script to look up a location by ref code

Since this is the only requirement you've stated, I would recommend using a dict where keys are ref codes and values are addresses.

I'm not sure why you are asking about "file types".  It seems you already have all this information stored in a spreadsheet - no need to write a new file.

Comment: the spreadsheet it is stored in is terrible (address are broken up into multiple cells, etc) I think it would be worth it to spend an hour or two reformatting the address/ref codes info because the script will save me countless hours for the spreadsheets it will be building